# understanding Parallel.Invoke, creation and reusing of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to understand how `Parallel.Invoke` creates and reuses threads.
I ran the following example code (from MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class ThreadLocalDemo
{
        static void Main()
        {
            // Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
            ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
            {
                return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            });

            // Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
            Action action = () =>
            {
                // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the
                // first action to run on this thread.
                bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;

                Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
            };

            // Launch eight of them. On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames
            Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

            // Dispose when you are done
            ThreadName.Dispose();
        }
}
```

As I understand it, `Parallel.Invoke` tries to create 8 threads here - one for each action. So it creates the first thread, runs the first `action`, and by that gives a `ThreadName` to the thread. Then it creates the next thread (which gets a different `ThreadName`) and so on.

If it cannot create a new thread, it will reuse one of the threads created before. In this case, the value of `repeat` will be `true` and we can see this in the console output.

Is this correct until here?

The second-last comment ("Launch eight of them. On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames") implies that the threads created by `Invoke` correspond to the available cpu threads of the processor: on 4 cores we have 8 cpu threads, at least one is busy (running the operating system and stuff), so `Invoke` can only use 7 different threads, so we must get at least one `"repeat"`.

Is my interpretation of this comment correct?

I ran this code on my PC which has an Intel® Core™ i7-2860QM processor (i.e. 4 cores, 8 cpu threads). I expected to get at least one `"repeat"`, but I didn't. When I changed the `Invoke` to take 10 instead of 8 actions, I got this output:

```
ThreadName = Thread6
ThreadName = Thread8
ThreadName = Thread6 (repeat)
ThreadName = Thread5
ThreadName = Thread3
ThreadName = Thread1
ThreadName = Thread10
ThreadName = Thread7
ThreadName = Thread4
ThreadName = Thread9
```

So I have at least 9 different threads in the console application. This contradicts the fact that my processor only has 8 threads.

So I guess some of my reasoning from above is wrong. Does `Parallel.Invoke` work differently than what I described above? If yes, how?

Comment: You can disprove your logic with a simple test, try creating a thread for every file on your hard disk, you will soon discover just cos it made one, doesnt mean it has 1 per cpu/core

Comment: Parallel uses threads from the Threadpool.  Whose job it is to use the processor as efficiently as possible.  Having more threads than processor cores is not efficient, the threadpool manager intentionally delays the extra ones.  Which is why you see the same thread being used more than once.  Lots of existing material about the .NET threadpool, put it in the Google search box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass less then 10 items to `Parallel.Invoke`, and you don't specify `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in options (so - your case), it will just run them all in parallel on thread pool sheduler using rougly the following code:

```
var actions = new [] { action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action };
var tasks = new Task[actions.Length];
for (int index = 1; index < tasks.Length; ++index)
    tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(actions[index]);
tasks[0] = new Task(actions[0]);
tasks[0].RunSynchronously();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

So just a regular `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If you will look at max number of threads in thread pool

```
int th, io;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out th, out io);
Console.WriteLine(th);
```

You will see some big number, like 32767. So, number of threads on which `Parallel.Invoke` will be executed (in your case) are not limited to number of cpu cores at all. Even on 1-core cpu it might run 8 threads in parallel.

You might then think, why some threads are reused at all? Because when work is done on thread pool thread - that thread is returned to the pool and is ready to accept new work. Actions from your example basically do no work at all and complete very fast. So sometimes first thread started via `Task.Factory.StartNew` has already completed your action and is returned to the pool before all subsequent threads were started. So that thread is reused.

By the way, you can see `(repeat)` in your example with 8 actions, and even with 7 if you try hard enough, on a 8 core (16 logical cores) processor.

UPDATE to answer your comment. Thread pool scheduler will not necessary create new threads immediately. There is min and max number of threads in thread pool. How to see max I already shown above. To see min number:

```
int th, io;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out th, out io);
```

This number will usually be equal to the number of cores (so for example 8). Now, when you request new action to be performed on thread pool thread, and number of threads in a thread pool is less than minimum - new thread will be created immeditely. However, if number of available threads is greater than minimum - certain delay will be introduced before creating new thread (I don't remember how long exactly unfortunately, about 500ms).

Statement you added in your comment I highly doubt can execute in 2-3 seconds. For me it executes for 0.3 seconds max. So when first 8 threads are created by thread pool, there is that 500ms delay before creating 9th. During that delay, some (or all) of first 8 threads are completed their job and are available for new work, so there is no need to create new thread and they can be reused.

To verify this, introduce bigger delay:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
    ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
    {
        return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    });

    // Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the
        // first action to run on this thread.
        bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;            
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
        Thread.Sleep(1000000);
    };
    int th, io;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out th, out io);
    Console.WriteLine("cpu:" + Environment.ProcessorCount);
    Console.WriteLine(th);        
    Parallel.Invoke(Enumerable.Repeat(action, 100).ToArray());        

    // Dispose when you are done
    ThreadName.Dispose();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You will see that now thread pool has to create new threads every time (much more than there are cores), because it cannot reuse previous threads while they are busy.

You can also increase number of min threads in thread pool, like this:

```
int th, io;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out th, out io);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, io);
```

This will remove the delay (until 100 threads are created) and in above example you will notice that.

Comment: You say the only reason that threads are reused is that some actions are finished before the scheduler has started all actions. I modified the code such that this is not the case any more: I put `long i = 100000000; while (i > 0) { i--; }` between the `bool repeat = ...;` and `Console.WriteLine(...);` lines. This makes each action take around 2-3 seconds. Still, only 9 different threads are used instead of 10.

Comment: To measure the time, I had this code inside the `action` curly brackets: `Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start(); bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated; long i = 100000000; while (i > 0) { i--; } Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}" , ThreadName.Value, (repeat ? "(repeat)" : "")); Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);` It gave me outputs between 2 and 3 seconds.

Comment: @Kjara ensure then that ALL of them run between 2-3 seconds. Because if even one runs in less than thread pool thread creation delay - it will be free for new work. But anyway, just introduce big delay with Thread.Sleep(1000000) and run 100 actions in parallel to verify my point. No need to test on edge cases.

Comment: But if I change the start value for `i` to `500000000` (results in around 14 seconds for each action), I can see that new threads are created and none are reused. Maybe the delay before creating new threads is higher on my PC. How can I retrieve that delay time?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not configurable but might be different in different .NET framework versions. I use .NET 4.5.2 for those tests, and which one you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135963/discussion-between-kjara-and-evk).

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, threads are organized (and possessed by) the task scheduler. Primary purpose of the task scheduler is to keep all CPU cores used as much as possible with useful work.

Under the hood, scheduler is using the thread pool, and then size of the thread pool is the way to fine-tune usefulness of operations executed on CPU cores.

Now this requires some analysis. For instance, thread switching costs CPU cycles and it is not useful work. On the other hand, when one thread executes one task on a core, all other tasks are stalled and they are not progressing on that core. I believe that is the core reason why the scheduler is usually starting two threads per core, so that at least some movement is visible in case that one task takes longer to complete (like several seconds).

There are corollaries to this basic mechanism. When some tasks take long time to complete, scheduler starts new threads to compensate. That means that long-running task will now have to compete for the core with short-running tasks. In that way, short tasks will be completed one after another, and long task will slowly progress to its completion as well.

Bottom line is that your observations about threads are generally correct, but not entirely true in specific situations. In concrete execution of a number of tasks, scheduler might choose to raise more threads, or to keep going with the default. That is why you will sometimes notice that number of threads differs.

Remember the goal of the game: Utilize CPU cores with *useful* work as much as possible, while at the same time making all tasks move, so that the application doesn't look like frozen. Historically, people used to try to reach these goals with many different techniques. Analysis had shown that many of those techniques were applied randomly and didn't really increase CPU utilization. That analysis has lead to introduction of task schedulers in .NET, so that fine-tuning can be coded once and be done well.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have at least 9 different threads in the console application. This contradicts the fact that my processor only has 8 threads.

A thread is a very much overloaded term. It can mean, at the very least: (1) something you sew with, (2) a bunch of code with associated state, that is represented by an OS handle, and (3) an execution pipeline of a CPU. The `Thread.CurrentThread` refers to (2), the "processor thread" that you mentioned refers to (3).

The existence of a (2)-thread is not predicated on the existence of (3)-thread, and the number of (2)-threads that exist on any particular system is pretty much limited by available memory and OS design. The existence of (2)-thread doesn't imply execution of (2)-thread at any given time (unless you use APIs that guarantee that).

Furthermore, if a (2)-thread executes at some point - implying a temporary 1:1 binding between (2)-thread and (3)-thread, there is no implication that the thread will continue executing in general, and of course neither is there an implication that the thread will continue executing on the same (3)-thread if it continues executing at all.

So, even if you have "caught" the execution of a (2)-thread on a (3)-thread by some side effect, e.g. console output, as you did, that doesn't necessarily imply anything about any other (2)-threads and (3)-threads at that point.

On to your code:

```
// If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the
// first action to run on this thread.   <-- this refers to (2)-thread, NOT (3)-thread.
```

`Parallel.Invoke` *is not precluded from* (in terms of specifications) creating as many new (2)-threads as there are arguments passed to it. The actual number of (2)-threads created may be all the way from zero to a hero, since to call `Parallel.Invoke` there must be an existing (2)-thread with some code that calls this API. So, no new (2)-threads need to be created at all, for example. Whether the (2)-threads created by `Parallel.Invoke` execute on any particular number of (3)-threads concurrently is beyond your control either.

So that explains the behavior you see. You conflated (2)-threads with (3)-threads, and assumed that `Parallel.Invoke` does something specific it in fact is not guaranteed to do. Citing [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netframework-4.8):

> No guarantees are made about the order in which the operations execute or whether they execute in parallel.

This implies that `Invoke` is free to run the actions on dedicated (2)-threads if it so wishes. And that is what you observed.